# populate select tag ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i want to following select tag

```
<select>
<option value=10> 10% </option>
<option value=20> 20% </option>
<option value=30> 30% </option>
</select>
```

using

```
 ((0..10).to_a.collect {|r| ["#{r*10} %", r*10] })
```

will give structure like

```
[["0 %", 0], ["10 %", 10], ["20 %", 20], ["30 %", 30]]
```

i wonder if this structure can be converted to something like this

```
[#<ratio id: 10, name: "10%">, #<id: 20, name:"20%">]
```

how to convert first structure to second strcuture

so i could use

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@arr,"id","name")
```

to populate the select_tag
or

is there any better way to do the same?

comments please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use [OpenStruct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) for this.

> An OpenStruct is a data structure, similar to a Hash, that allows the
>   definition of arbitrary attributes with their accompanying values.
>   This is accomplished by using Ruby’s metaprogramming to define methods
>   on the class itself.

```
require 'ostruct'
(0..10).map { |i| OpenStruct.new(:id => i*10, :name => "#{i*10}%") }
# => [#<OpenStruct id=0, name="0%">, #<OpenStruct id=10, name="10%">, ...
```

But if you need a real class, not anonymous class like OpenStruct, then just create this class instances inside the collect/map method:

```
class Ratio
    attr_reader :id, :name
    def initialize(id, name)
        @id = id; @name = name
    end
end
(0..10).map { |i| ratio = i*10; Ratio.new(ratio, "#{ratio}%") }
# => [#<Ratio: @id=0, @name="0%">, #<Ratio: @id=10, @name="10%">, ...
```

---

Maybe I misunderstood you a bit and you want to create this structure not from range, but from array `[["0 %", 0], ["10 %", 10], ["20 %", 20], ["30 %", 30]]` then the code is similar:

```
require 'ostruct'
arr = [["0 %", 0], ["10 %", 10], ["20 %", 20], ["30 %", 30]]
p arr.map { |name, id| OpenStruct.new(:id => id, :name => name) }
# => [#<OpenStruct id=0, name="0 %">, #<OpenStruct id=10, name="10 %">, #<OpenStruct id=20, name="20 %">, #<OpenStruct id=30, name="30 %">]
```

---

**UPDATE**
I found one corner case in usage of OpenStruct (looks like this is the case for **Ruby 1.8.7** only): `OpenStruct#id` will return `object_id` for `id` instead of field value:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p352 > o = OpenStruct.new :id => 10
 => #<OpenStruct id=10> 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 > o.id
(irb):4: warning: Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id
 => 70021843187380
```

There are two workarounds:

```
# 1. redefine OpenStruct#id method: 
OpenStruct.__send__(:define_method, :id) { @table[:id] }

# 2. dont use 'id' as a value and use any other value:
require 'ostruct'
(0..10).map { |i| OpenStruct.new(:value => i*10, :name => "#{i*10}%") } # 'value' instead of 'id'

...
options_from_collection_for_select(@arr, 'value', 'name')
```

I recommend you to use second approach.

Comment: thnx Alex.. also can you suggest some book or reference to start with data structures and metaprogramming in ruby.. that will be really helpful. i am currently working on some rails project and often need to use above structures.

Comment: @mashit, in my opinion the best place to stidy base class library is [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/). If you want to study ruby deeper, I can recommend *The Ruby Programing Language* by Matz. And for deeper metaprogramming understanding you can check book *Metaprogramming Ruby* by Perotta.

Comment: well there is some problem in the id the html generated - <option value="-630637738">10 %</option> <option value="-630638048">20 %</option> <option value="-630638348">30 %</option>.. i am using <%= select_tag "done_ratio",options_from_collection_for_select(@arr,:id,:name, default_sel) %>

Comment: also how to find an element in the new struture(the one created using openStruct)

Comment: @mashit, How to find: `@arr.find {|obj| obj.id == 20 } # => #<OpenStruct id=20, name="20%"> `

Comment: there is some issue with the structure,, [#<ratio id: 10, name: "10%">, #<id: 20, name:"20%">] is the need and what i am getting is [#<ratio id= 10, name= "10%">, #<id= 20, name="20%">] and may be this is the reason why there is some garbage value in "value" of options

Comment: @mashit, regarding ids, can you show me result of `p @arr` expression? According to [options_from_collection_for_select documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select) the code `options_from_collection_for_select(@arr, 'id', 'name')` should work.

Comment: id: 10, name: "10%" and not id=10, name="10%"

Comment: result of p @arr is [#<OpenStruct name="0%", id=0>, #<OpenStruct name="10%", id=10>, #<OpenStruct name="20%", id=20>, #<OpenStruct name="30%", id=30>]

Comment: yes using value(or any other var) inplace of id, does the job.. thnx a lot.. although there is no need to change the structure now. i am curious how can the structure be changed. from _field=value_ to _field:value_

Answer (score 1):

```
array = [["0 %", 0], ["10 %", 10], ["20 %", 20], ["30 %", 30]]
@arr = array.collect { |sub_array| Ratio.new(:id=>sub_array.last, :name=>sub_array.first) }
```

Comment: i am not following the class. i.e i am not using Ratio class

Comment: Friend I thought you are using the Ratio class.Okay no issues :)